# Avoid fast division (reciprocal)

Tags: c, math, precision

is there any way to write C code with divisions to command the compiler to not use fast division (by reciprocal math) at a few specific places in the code that need the precision of a regular division even when reciprocal math is allowed globally?

Ideally, there‘s a method that is not compiler-specific and would also survive fast-math and unsafe-math options of e.g. gcc.

Comment: Seeing as you're talking about a compiler optimization, I don't see how it **couldn't** be compiler specific.

Comment: There is no standard for optimization options, or in this case non-optimization options.

Comment: You are talking about floating-point arithmetic (not integer arithmetic), right?

Comment: why do you want that? Compilers never convert a floating-point division to a multiplication by its reciprocal without an explicit flag like `-ffast-math`, and integer division can always be converted to multiplication by the multiplicative inverse without any loss of precision

Answer (score 0):

You could provide your own divide function in a seperate file, say `divide.c`

```
double divide(double a, double b) { return a/b; }
```

write a corresponding header file `divide.h`

```
double divide(double a, double b);
```

and then write in your code

```
#include "divide.h"

int foo() {
    //...
    double x = divide(y,3.0);
}
```

Since the function divide is unknown to the compiler here, it cannot be optimized. So, the full division algorithm is applied.

Comment: Of course, this assumes that the `divide()` function is compiled without optimization.  Also, unless your toolchain performs link-time inlining, you end up with the overhead of a function call around the division, yet if it *does* perform link-time inlining then there is a risk that it also performs the unwanted division optimization at link time.

Comment: AND, since the success of this technique may therefore depend on the linker's behavior with respect to link-time optimization, it is not guaranteed reliable.

Comment: @John Bollinger: This does NOT require that divide is compiled without optimization. The compiler does not know the value of b, so it cannot replace a/b just by a*binv with a compile-time computed binv. Link time optimization might be an issue, but NOT inlining per-se. The linker would have to inspect the assembly and do optimizations based on the assembly.

Comment: AND, since this approach does not any compiler intrinsics, it works on any compiler. If you want more, you are anyway totally lost since C++ does not make any guarantees on floating point accuracy.

Comment: C++ is irrelevant, the question being about C.  Nevertheless, C does not make guarantees about precision of floating-point computations either, and that's the main point.  There is *no* compiler-independent way to ensure that a particular division will be performed as "regular division", whatever that may be.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an optimization #pragma to disable -ffast-math in specific code (or reverse it).

Be careful with using library functions, they were likely imported with **FAST_MATH** set, so might be using fast-math versions even in code where fast-math locally is disabled.